# Antlr whitespace token error

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I have the following grammar and I want to match the String "{name1, name2}". I just want lists of names/intergers with at least one element. However I get the error:
line 1:6 no viable alternative at character ' '
line 1:11 no viable alternative at character '}'
line 1:7 mismatched input 'name' expecting SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE

I would expect whitespaces and such are ignored... Also interesting is the error does not occur with input "{name1,name2}" (no space after ',').
Heres my gramar

```
grammar NusmvInput;
options {
  language = Java;
}
@header {
  package secltlmc.grammar;
}
@lexer::header {
  package secltlmc.grammar;
}
specification : 
     SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE EOF
     ;     
INTEGER 
    : ('0'..'9')+
    ;
SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE 
    : ('{' (NAME | INTEGER) (',' (NAME | INTEGER))* '}'  )
    ;
NAME 
    : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '$' | '#' | '-')*
    ;
WS 
    : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;} 
    ;
```

And this is my testing code

```
package secltlmc;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
            IOException, RecognitionException {
        CharStream stream = new ANTLRStringStream("{name1, name2}");
        NusmvInputLexer lexer = new NusmvInputLexer(stream);
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        NusmvInputParser parser = new NusmvInputParser(tokenStream);
        parser.specification();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse `SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE` with the lexer, i.e. you are trying to make it a single token. In reality, it looks like you want a multi-token production, since you'd like whitespace to be re-directed to hidden channel through `WS`.

You should change `SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE` from a lexer rule to a parser rule by changing its initial letter (or better yet, the entire name) to lower case.

```
specification : 
     simple_var_type EOF
     ;    

simple_var_type 
    : ('{' (NAME | INTEGER) (',' (NAME | INTEGER))* '}'  )
    ;
```

Comment: @HeinrichOdy My understanding is that lexer rules can use other lexer rules only explicitly. Parser rules use all lexer rules implicitly, because parser rules are of the higher level. The parser calls the lexer for the next token, the lexer delivers `WS` to the hidden channel, and moves on to the next token. You are also correct that you can use `WS` inside lexer rules explicitly.

Comment: Sry, for deleting my own comment... Picked your answer cause of making clear to me that within tokens whitespace-clearing does not work with hiding tokens, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The defintion of `SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE` specifies the following expression:

- Open `{`
- followed by one of `NAME` or `INTEGER`
- follwoed by zero or more of:

  - comma (`,`) followed by one of `NAME` or `INTEGER`
- followed by closing `}`

Nowhere does it allow white-space in the input (neither `NAME` nor `INTEGER` allows it either), so you get an error when you supply one

Try:

```
SIMPLE_VAR_TYPE 
: ('{' (NAME | INTEGER) (WS* ',' WS* (NAME | INTEGER))* '}'  )
;
```

Comment: Probably I should also add WS to '{'WS* ... WS*'}', but I see where you are heading, thanks :)